# How to convert javascript object to javascript array in view file?

Tags: javascript

I have a jQuery file that passes a data object to a script in a view file in a Laravel 8 site. I am trying to convert this into a javascript array that can be used in a d3 visualization. The original data passed looks like this (from console):

```
points: 
    floor_data:
        0:{location_id: 134, count: 1}
        1:{location_id: 136, count: 1}
        2:{location_id: 1387, count: 6}
     floor_number:1
     located_inside: 3
[[Prototype]]:Object
```

I can extract the first three items (which are the important items in this case) into an array that looks like this (from console):

```
0:
     count:1
     location_id:134
     [[Prototype]]: Object
1:
     count:1
     location_id:136
     [[Prototype]]:Object
2:
     count:6
     location_id:1387
     [[Prototype]]:Object
length:3
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
```

Not being a javaScript Ninja, I'm not sure what I'm looking at, but it looks like an array of objects, but at the end it indicates the array is empty (`[[Prototype]]:Array(0)`)

I want to get the data into an array that looks like this:

```
const visitors = [
        {
            name: 134,
            total: 1,
            color: "blue"
        },
        {
            name: 136,
            total: 1,
            color: "blue"
        },
        {
            name: 1387,
            total: 6,
            color: "red"
        }];
```

The code I wrote to parse the data into that array looks like this:

```
console.log('All the items are here:', items)

const colors = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue"];

const vis = [];

if (items.length) {
     console.log(items[0].location_id)
     let x = 0;
     for( let i=0; i<items.length; i++){
         console.log(items[i].location_id);
         if (items[i].location_id !== undefined) {
             console.log('i  = ', i);
             console.log('First location id = ', items[i].location_id);
             vis[x]['location_id'] = items[i].location_id;
             console.log('vis location id = ', vis[x]['location_id']);
             vis[x]['count'] = items[i].count;
             if(x < 5) {
                 vis[x]['color'] = colors[i];
                 } else {
                 vis[x]['color'] = "red";
             }
             x++;
         }
     }
} else {
    console.log('there are no items')
}
console.log('Vistors new array: ', vis)
```

The first two `console.log(items[0].location_id)` gives me the number 134, which is correct. The next `console.log('i  = ', i);` gives me the index 0 which is correct.
The next `console.log('First location id = ', items[i].location_id);` gives me an error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'location_id')`
I don't know why it is giving me this error when I was already able to log `items[0].location_id`

Here is the full console display:

[image]

What is it I am doing incorrectly in parsing this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not because of `console.log('First location id = ', items[i].location_id);`. This is because you didn't initialize `vis[x]` as an object.

```
if(items[i].location_id !== undefined){
    console.log('i  = ', i);
    console.log('First location id = ', items[i].location_id);

    // Initialize vis[x] as an object
    vis[x] = {};

    vis[x]['location_id'] = items[i].location_id;
    //rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: let me know if your problem is solved or note. if it is solved, please upvote & accept my answer.

Comment: Adding that piece of code broke the whole thing. Now I'm getting the error that the code can't find the function by which the data was being passed, even after removing the  `vis[x] = {};` and giving it a hard refresh.

Comment: Actually, I'm now getting `heatmap:659 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'`

Comment: I'm sorry, while I was awaiting a response I made some incomplete edits to the page and that's what created the issue. Your solution worked. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never initialising `vis[x]`

After you set `let x = 0`, do this: `vis[x] = []`

And after you increment x with `x++`, do it again: `vis[x] = []`

Explanation:
It's complaining that it can't set property "location_id" on undefined. The only place this happens is on the line `vis[x]['location_id'] = items[i].location_id;`, which means `vis[x]` is undefined. You need to define it first.